# How do I plot vertical strips in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to show the value of a 0 or 1 array on a plot with other timeseries.

How can I achieve something like the grey lines below - except mine will oscillate a lot more.

[image]series.

For example, how to add osc here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import pandas as pd

n = 100
x = range(n)
y = np.random.rand(100)
osc = np.random.randint(2, size=n)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show(block=True)
```

Comment: `ax.axvspan(x0,x1,color=...,alpha=0.5)` in a loop

Comment: Could you demo this with the example in the question please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can loop through the values and call `axvspan(x0,x1,color=...,alpha=...)`;

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 100
x = range(n)
y = np.random.randn(100).cumsum()
osc = np.random.randint(2, size=n)

plt.plot(x, y, color='crimson')
for x0, x1, os in zip(x[:-1], x[1:], osc):
    if os:
        plt.axvspan(x0, x1, color='blue', alpha=0.2, lw=0)
plt.margins(x=0)
plt.show()
```

Note that only the first 99 values of `osc` are used, as there are only 99 intervals.

[image: axvspan in a loop]

Comment: Perfect. Nice solution

Answer (score 0):

See code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 100
x = range(n)
y = np.random.rand(100)
osc = np.random.randint(2, size=n)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.axvspan(0,5,facecolor='grey', alpha=0.4)
plt.show()
```

Documentation on `axvspan` can be found here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan.html.

Similarly you can use `axvline` for just vertical lines.

Comment: That doesn't use osc does it?

Comment: What do you mean by osc? I do not know what it means. 
If you want to add the grey areas to only negative slopes of the graph you can compute the gradient of the data points and index all negative values. These indices you can then use to add the grey areas.

Comment: osc is the oscillator in my code - the thing I want to plot